# Escaping or Using C String in SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, c, string, escaping

I'm using Connector C API to connect to mysql database. I'm having issue with using the value of a c string in a sql statement.

```
char *somequery = "SELECT username, password from tableABC WHERE username='john'";
```

The above is working fine, if I user a simple text 'john'. But if I replace it with a string (which is set earlier in the program), it doesn't work and breaks down with a 500 error.

```
char *ghob = "john";
char *somequery = "SELECT username, password from tableABC WHERE username=ghob";
```

I have tried a few things, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprintf () lets you to store formatted data as a string. 
Using sprintf() you can to store the value of ghob into somequery.

Like below.

```
#define MAX_QUERY_LENGTH 1024 //defines max possible query lengh

char *somequery = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_QUERY_LENGTH);
char *ghob = "bobmarley";
sprintf(somequery, "SELECT username, password from tableABC WHERE username='%s'",ghob);
```

Or

```
char somequery[MAX_QUERY_LENGTH];
char *ghob = "bobmarley";
sprintf(somequery, "SELECT username, password from tableABC WHERE username='%s'",ghob);
```

Either way it should be fine.

```
  printf("%s", somequery);
```

printing somequery will result in

```
SELECT username, password from tableABC WHERE username='bobmarley'
```

Comment: doesn't the sql query require single quotes? is username='%s' the right way?

Comment: Yes ofcourse...

Comment: We always remind folk that this simple text insertion is not production quality: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @GemTaylor It would be helpful, if you add a answer including a reason as to why.

Comment: btw, the string to be used is sanitized, size limited, null-terminated and escaped properly.. do I still need to worry Gem?

Comment: OK, if it is already sanitised then perhaps OK. At some point you do have to do the string concatenation :-)

Comment: Yes, You need enough memory to fit the whole string. Either statically or dynamically allocated.

Comment: I have edited my answer, take a look.

Comment: char somequery[MAX_QUERY_LENGTH]; char *ghob = "bobmarley"; sprintf(somequery, "SELECT username, password from tableABC WHERE username='%s'", ghob);

Comment: If copying takes place between objects that overlap as a result of a call to sprintf() or snprintf(), the results are undefined. @AhmadBilal got your point,

Comment: leave this last comment of yours as it is, since it would be helpful for others.The rest you can delete.